# Where can i override or disable the 'change app aspect ratio' button in my app?

Tags: android

When you press the multi window button on Samsung Galaxy S9, you can see a button on thumbnail view, that changes the aspect ratio of the app. It is the blue button in the bottom right.

How do I disable this button? 
Where can I handle this event?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, you don't want your app to permit multi window?

Comment: In the image i have attached, in the multiview, on the bottom right side you can see a floating button. I want to know what method does that button trigger, so i can handle it, or where i can disable it. I know that most apps have it disabled, but i dont know how i can disable it on my app.

Comment: Inside your Application add this : android:resizeableActivity="false" (in your manifest.xml), if it does not work add this `android:resizeableActivity="false"` inside of every Activity you have in manifest.xml